# Ansible module include_vars hangs

Tags: ansible

My playbook:

```
- name: My playbook
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files: 
    - ../data/my-static-vars.yaml

  tasks:
    - name: Load vars file {{ myDynamicVars }} 
      include_vars: 
        file: "{{ myDynamicVars }}"
```

This playbook hang with output as below:

```
TASK [Load vars file ../../../input/data/my-dynamic-vars.yaml] ****************************************************
Monday 08 November 2021  08:46:44 +0000 (0:00:00.665)       0:01:01.363 *******
```

The path value "../../../input/data/my-dynamic-vars.yaml" is valid and a good YAML vars file.
The same task sometimes able to run correctly, but most time just hang as above.
I have the same task used in different playbooks, some worked some not.

Any suggestions?

Comment: the problem if exists is not in your playbook  but in your var file

Comment: But the the same var file have times read fine. I observed if I remove some tasks AFTER this task, this task worked. Not sure if related to the removal or just got lucky after the removal. Still do more tests.

Answer (score 0):

Put '---' at beginning of the var file, removed trailing spaces on heading comments.